# How to find records within a certain timeframe based on another field

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I find all records 7 days before a field in an SQL database?

I need to find all transaction dates that were placed 7 days before the pickup date of the same record.

I am currently using SequelPro so that my have an effect on available syntaxes.

This is currently my table that I am pulling the records from.

[image: photo of table and its content]

This is the exact question I am being asked;

Write a query to display all details of transactions that were made at least one
week before the pickup date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it straightforward?

```sql
SELECT * FROM TransactionTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(pickupdate, transactiondate) >= 7;
```